# AWS EC2 instance periodically drops security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am using EC2 with Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Spring Boot application. This deployment connects to an RDS MySQL instance and an assigned default security group allows the communication.

For a 3rd time, I have found the security group has been dropped from the EC2s list of groups, resulting in degraded Spring Boot, in which Boot is stuck in a startup loop (I am not sure why brought it down)

A separate Boot/EBS deployment uses this same group for RDS connectivity, and has never experienced this.

Has anyone else experienced this? Logs reveal nothing other than connection timeout to RDS.

Comment: Is the security group actually selected in the EB Environment's configuration in the instance section?

Comment: I am not sure which view that is. The group shows up in the EC2 instance view under security groups after I re add it using with Actions>Networking>Change Security Groups. In the EB config view, I don't see options for security group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is you are attaching the security groups to the instance using EC2 console instead of using EB environment's configuration.

[image]

Go to EB console, chose your environment, click on configuration.

[image]

Click Edit on the Instances section, add security groups from this location. Doing so will ensure that all your security groups are applied when EB is creating instances as an example when it scale-out.

[image]

Comment: Sure enough, the group didn't show up under EB config even though it was applied to the EC2 instance and allowing inbound/outbound traffic. I was able to reproduce losing the group by rebuilding. This seems like a gap with the UI.

Comment: I would not consider this to be a gap in the UI. You might want to add an SG to one instance without affecting other instances in the same EB environment for debugging purposes or for some other reason. I would not expect adding the SG to the instance level to affect my EB configuration.

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot this issue, you can use AWS CloudTrail. Using AWS CloudTrail, you can trace who is detaching security group from the related AWS EC2 Instance. This kind of event is logged as ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute with event source as ec2.amazonaws.com.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-tutorial.html) you can find AWS CloudTrail user guide.

*Note*:Typically, CloudTrail delivers an event within 15 minutes of the API call/event.